# API processing time

Tags: apex

I am trying to access the exact processing time of an insert or update of a record via REST through APEX. What class should i use in my code to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that the processing time will vary from call to call because of other server activity, whether the table is already cached, how much data is in the table, how up to date the table index is and so on. So it always pays to make multiple measurements.

The call I uses is [System.currentTimeMillis](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_currentTimeMillis) which on Salesforce does increment every millisecond:

```
Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Code to time goes here
Long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.debug((t2 - t1) + ' ms');
```

If the code you are timing runs in less than a few milliseconds you can wrap it in a loop (say of 100 repeats) and then divide the resulting figure by the number of repeats.